# Mac to Linux formatting

Tags: macbook, format, apple

Hey all I'm trying to convert a mac to a Ubuntu Linux system and am having trouble erasing all the software off the Mac. The command function for the Mac formatting is not functioning. Any ideas no matter how left field will be appreciated.

Comment: What Mac is it, specifically? Have you tried just telling the Ubuntu installer to use the entire disk? In general, you don't need to erase the disk before installing Ubuntu; Ubuntu's installer takes care of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to hand-delete Mac software first. Backup all the files you want to keep (and be sure Linux can read them), boot from a Linux install medium (USB Key, CD, ...), choose "Install to disk" and it will overwrite (destroy) all the Macness.